# Information popup box

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

I'm looking for an information popup box like here on this site:

[Yahoo answers example](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AmGqRfz4d6omuA4g6kPUJgUk5XNG;_ylv=3?qid=20100701073554AAXPoHG)

Here if you hover mouse on question author or answer author usernames small nice popup box will appear, that queries some information with ajax. I need exactly the same thing... I need to display small popup box when the mouse is over the link and call some information from database.

Do you happen to have javascript for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a list of plugins you can use with jQuery: [30 Stylish jQuery Tooltip Plugins For Catchy Designs](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)